# These four numbers make 25

Tags: mathematics

> The sum of the whole is 25
>   Large and small are different by 4
>   The first is 2 times the fourth
>   Third is equal to first

**What are the four numbers?**
This is really bugging me can not figure it out, thanks for all your help....

Source: [This thing right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7UNY.jpg)

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Comment: Do you allow non-integer solutions too?

Answer (score 39):

could be:

> 8,5,8,4

fits all conditions:

> $4*2 = 8 \implies 8-4 = 4 \implies 8+5+8+4 = 25 \implies 1st=3rd=8$

Comment: This is the only integer solution.

Answer (score 24):

by putting all conditions except "*Large and small are different by 4*" as letters below

> $2a$,$b$,$2a$,$a$ where sum is $25$

should be these numbers. so we can conclude that

**First condition:**

> $2a$ could be biggest while $b$ could be lowest, so $2a-b=4$

**Second condition:**

> $b$ could be biggest, $b-a=4$ since $2a$ is greater than $a$.

and **Last condition**:

> $2a$ could be biggest and $a$ could be lowest. $a=4$ then.

In other words,

> $5a+b=25$ where $2a-b=4$ or $a=4$ or $b-a=4$

so using first condition;

> $7a-4=25$ so $a$ is not integer.

or using second condition;

> $6a+4=25$ so $a$ is not integer again.

and using the last condition

> $a=4$, $2a=8$ and $b=5$

it seems last condition is the only solution we could have.

Answer (score 9):

> The first is 2 times the fourth
>   Third is equal to first

We define the numbers as **2a**, **b**, **2a**, **a**

> The sum of the whole is 25

We have **2a + b + 2a + a = 25**

> Large and small are different by 4

We have **max(a, b, 2a) - min(a, b, 2a) = 4**

---

[Solving the 2 equations...](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5a%2Bb%3D25,max(a,b,2a)-min(a,b,2a)%3D4)

We got 2 solutions.

> **8**, **5**, **8**, **4**
>  **7**, **7.5**, **7**, **3.5**

Answer (score 6):

> To expand on a process to get to @Preet's answer.
>  
>
>  We know that the biggest number must be bigger than 6. Since $25 / 4 = 6.25$
>  So the smallest number must be greater than 3. 
>  We know that some number is double the other. If the smallest was 5 than the smallest double is 10, $10 - 5 = 5  > 4$ and it can be easily shown that the difference gets bigger as the small number gets bigger. 
>  We now know that 4 must be the smallest, and the biggest is 8.
>  Since 8 is double of 4 we know that 4 is the fourth, and 8 is the first, because no other doubles can fit between these numbers
>  Since the third is the same as the first, we end up with **8, _, 8, 4**
>  We have shown that this is the only integer solution. Using the same logic it may be possible to show that there is only an integer solution.

A proof of whether or not a non-integer solution is possible:

> We know that for any value of the smallest number greater than 4, it is impossible for one number to be doubled of another. 
> We know that $2.25$ is a naive lower bound for the smallest as well. Since $25 / 4 = 6.25$ and $6.25 - 4 = 2.25$
>  So the lowest number is between 2.25 and 4.
>  2.25 is only possible if all 4 values were 6.25 (an immediate contradiction). 
> If we refine the equation such that 3 are the same, and the 4th is 4 less:
>  $4x - 4 = 25$ 
>  $x = 29 / 4  = 7.25$ 
> So the largest number is greater than 7.25 so the lowest must be larger than 3.25
>  The maximum largest number is just under 8 (limit) if one of the two remaining numbers is less than 4. than the other must be greater than 9 to reach 25 as a sum. 9 is impossible so this is a contradiction. 
>  So one of the middle numbers must be double the smallest. (For any number other than 4, the largest will not be double that of the smallest). 
>  Furthermore we know that one number must exist twice, and it cannot be the smallest. If the largest was copied, than the other must be double of the smallest. $x + 2x + z + z = 25$ 
>  $3x + z + z = 25$ 
>  $z = x + 4$ 
>  $5x + 8 = 25$ 
>  $5x = 17$ 
>  $x = 3.4$
>  So we found another solution.
>  **3.4, 6.8, 7.4, 7.4** 
>  Finally the last case is if the 2 non-extrema are the same. They must also be double the smallest so we get: 
>  $x + 2x + 2x + x+4 = 25$
>  $6x+4 = 25$ 
>  $6x = 21$ 
>  $x = 3.5$
>  so another solution is
>  **7, 7.5, 7, 3.5**

Comment: seems that `3.4, 6.8, 7.4, 7.4` is not a valid answer as it cannot fulfill  `Third is equal to first` and `The first is 2 times the fourth` at the same time

Comment: Oh that is a good point. I didn't realise there was a constraint that the one that is double the smallest must also have a pair.

Answer (score 1):

It is straightforward:

> 1) $~ x + y + z + w = 25$
>      2) $~ x - w = 4$
>      3) $~ x = 2 \times w$
>      4) $~ x = z$

Then

> From 2) and 3) we get: $x = w + 4 = 2 \times w ~~ \implies w = 4$

From there you are done:

> $x = 2 \times w = 2 \times 4 = 8$
>  $x = z$    therefore   $z=8$
>  $x + y + z + w = 8 + y + 8 + 4 = 25 \implies y = 5$

Comment: Not a given x is max and w is min

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

> The numbers are $2a,b,2a,a$. The sum is $25$, so $5a+b=25$ means that $b$ is a multiple of $5$. A simple check using condition (2) means $b\ne0$ as $2a=4$ gives a total of $10$. $b=10$ fails because then $a=3$ and $10-3=7\ne4$.
> So $b=5, a=4$ and the numbers are $8,5,8,4$.

Answer (score -1):

What are the four numbers?

- The sum of the whole is 25:

> $a + b + c + d = 25$

- Large and small are different by 4:

> $x - y = 4$ where $x > y$ and $x$ could be ($a$ or $b$) and y could be ($b$ or $d$)

- The first is 2 times the fourth:

> $(a = 2d) ... 2d + b + c + d = 25 => 3d + b + c = 25$

- Third is equal to first:

> $(c = a = 2d) ... 2d + b + 2d + d = 25 => 5d + b = 25$

The step 2 is the key to solve the problem. Just replace a, b or d for x and y (excluding c since `c = a`)... 
You will find 2 "integer" solutions:

### Solution 1:

> when $x = a = 2d$, and $y = d$
>  $x - y = 4 => 2d - d = 4 => d = 4$

Replace that in the last equation:

> $5d + b = 25 => 5*4 + b = 25 => 20 + b = 25 => b = 5$
>
>  **Solution:** $a = 8, b = 5, c = 8, d = 4$

### Solution 2: when `x = b`, and `y = a = 2d`

```
b - a = 4 => b = 4 + a => same as => b = 4 + 2d
```

Replace that in the last equation, to find d:

```
5d + b = 25 => 5d + (4 + 2d) = 25 => 7d = 25 - 4 => 7d = 21 => d = 3
```

And then in the case equation, to find b:

```
b = 4 + 2*3 => b = 10
```

- a = 2d = 2*3 = 6
- b = 10
- c = 2d = 6
- d = 3

I have to remove this 2nd solution since violates the rule #2. 10-3 = 7... in other words, `y` can't be `a` since `a` is not the smallest (`a > d`), Thanks @Rubio.

All the possible cases are:

> * $a - b = 4$, it is possible $a > b$ (no-integer solution)
>  * $a - d = 4$, we are sure $a > d$ (integer solution)
>  * $b - d = 4$, it is possible $b > d$ (no-integer solution)

Note these are NOT a valid cases:

> * $b - a = 4$, we are sure $a$ is NOT the smallest, $a > d$ (error for solution 2)
>  * $d - b = 4$, we are sure $d$ is NOT the largest, $a > d$
>  * $a - c = 4$, impossible $a = c$
>  * $d - a = 4$, impossible $a > d$

Comment: 6,10,6,3 violates Line 2 constraint (which would better have been said as larg*est* and small*est*, but the intent is pretty clear).  And how is any of your answer substantively different from the several that preceded it (other than half of it being wrong)?

Comment: Thanks for all the help, made my day better....